# How to create condition like regex for matching urls in if else condition

Tags: javascript

I have following 7 URLs where there is a common pattern like and I need to write logic to differentiate these kind of urls and only the numbers in the url like 99031 or 2768 are changing but rest remains the same for all urls.

https://hiringapp-671.generic.com/SelfService

https://hiringapp-671.generic.com/SelfService/MyProfile

https://hiringapp-671.generic.com/SelfService/MyProfile/Application/Show/99031/Withdraw

https://hiringapp-671.generic.com/SelfService/MyProfile/ApplicationShow/99031

https://hiringapp-671.generic.com/Vacancies/2768/Application/New/1

https://hiringapp-671.generic.com/Vacancies/2768/Application/1/Confirmation#/Vacancies/ID/Application/New/1

i tried with the following generic if statement but i want a unique match for every such urls pls suggest how to use regex or form a pattern,

```
if  (window.location.href.indexOf("SelfService") > -1)

if  (window.location.href.indexOf("SelfService/MyProfile") > -1)

if  (window.location.href.indexOf("/Withdraw") > -1)

if  (window.location.href.indexOf("Application/New") > -1)

if  (window.location.href.indexOf("Confirmation#/Vacancies/ID/Application/New") > -1)
```

its working sometimes and sometimes not what is the best way to form a condition based on the above pattern of urls using ways like regex etc,

Comment: You need to write it or you need someone else to write it?

Comment: Hi @EternalHour so pls suggest the best method if anyone could write the code would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @J.ScottElblein condition working but again /SelfService is present on multiple urls so it is matched multiple times how to create condition that matches one url only once.

Comment: For starters, I wouldn't do individual `if`s. I'd use `if/elseif/else` or `switch` statements.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein thanks can you suggest in regex and match each url only once

Answer (score 0):

Well, in regex, `\d*` will find the numbers. I would do an `if/elseif/else` or `switch` type of handler, starting with the longest item first.

Something along the lines of this, to get you pointed in the right direction (pseudocode-ish):

```
var str = (the URL to check);

if (str.match('SelfService\/MyProfile\/Application\/Show\/\d*\/Withdraw')) {

    // Handle SelfService/MyProfile/Application/Show/<numbers>/Withdraw

} elseif (str.match('SelfService\/MyProfile\/Application\/Show\/\d*')) {

    // Handle SelfService/MyProfile/Application/Show/<numbers>
    // NOTE: since the URL containing 'Withdraw' was already handled above.

} elseif (str.match('SelfService')) {

    // This could also be handled using `indexof` if you wanted. May have better performance than a regex.

}
```

And so on.

Take a look here:
https://regex101.com/r/S3ohTR/1